# Function calling - complex values and pointers

Tags: c++

I wrote a c++ code, calling a function with using complex value as you can see in following, when I compile my code I face to this error : " error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type int& from a temporary of type double **complex** (*)[4][4]"
I can not find the place where I made a mistake.Can you please help me to debug my code?

```
void SCMA_En (char in_bit [2], double _Complex in_cb[4][4], double _Complex *out_cw[4])
{
    if ((in_bit[0] == 0) && (in_bit[1] == 0)) {
        for  (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            out_cw[i] = in_cb[i][0];
        }
    }
    else if ((in_bit[0] == 0) && (in_bit[1] == 1)) {
        for  (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            out_cw[i] = in_cb[i][1];
        }
    }   
    else if ((in_bit[0] == 1) && (in_bit[1] == 0)) {
        for  (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            out_cw[i] = in_cb[i][2];
        }
    }
    else if ((in_bit[0] == 1) && (in_bit[1] == 1)) {
        for  (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            out_cw[i] = in_cb[i][3];
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{

double _Complex CB_1[4][4]; 
double _Complex CB_2[4][4]; 
double _Complex CB_3[4][4]; 
double _Complex CB_4[4][4]; 
double _Complex CB_5[4][4]; 
double _Complex CB_6[4][4]; 

char En_in1[2];
char En_in2[2];
char En_in3[2];
char En_in4[2];
char En_in5[2];
char En_in6[2];

char    input_user1[1024];
char    input_user2[1024];
char    input_user3[1024];
char    input_user4[1024];
char    input_user5[1024];
char    input_user6[1024];

CB_1 = { {0, 0, 0, 0} , { -0.1815-0.1318*I, 0.6351-0.4615*I, 0.6315+0.4615*I, 0.1815+0.1318*I } , { 0, 0, 0, 0 } , { 0.7851, -0.2243, 0.2243, -0.7851} };

CB_2 = { { 0.7851, -0.2243, 0.2243, -0.7851 } , { 0, 0, 0, 0 } , { -0.1815-0.1318*I , -0.6351-0.4615*I , 0.6351+0.4615*I , 0.1815+0.1318*I } , { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0} };

CB_3 = { {-0.6351+0.4615*I , 0.1815-0.1318*I , -0.1815+0.1318*I , 0.6351-0.4615*I } , { 0.1392-0.1759*I , 0.4873-0.6156*I , -0.4873+0.6156*I , -0.1392+0.1759*I } , { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } , { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } };

CB_4 = { { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } , { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } , { 0.7851 , -0.2243 , 0.2243 ,  -0.7851 } , { -0.0055-0.2242*I , -0.0193-0.7848*I , 0.0193+0.7848*I , 0.0055+0.2242*I } };

CB_5 = { { -0.0055-0.2242*I , -0.0193-0.7848*I , 0.0193+0.7848*I , 0.0055+0.2242*I } , { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } , { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } , { -0.6351+0.4615*I , 0.1815-0.1318*I , -0.1815+0.1318*I , 0.6351-0.4615*I } };

CB_6 = { { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } , { 0.785 , -0.2243 , 0.2243 , -0.7851 } , { 0.1392-0.1759*I , 0.4873-0.6156*I , -0.4873+0.6156*I , -0.1392+0.1759*I } , { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } };

for (i=0; i<init_num; i=i+2) {
    En_in1[0] = input_user1[i];
    En_in1[1] = input_user1[i+1];
    SCMA_En (En_in1,CB_1, &CW_U1);
}

for (i=0; i<init_num; i=i+2) {
    En_in2[0] = input_user2[i];
    En_in2[1] = input_user2[(i+1)];
    SCMA_En (En_in2,CB_2, &CW_U2 );
}

for (i=0; i<init_num; i=i+2) {
    En_in3[0] = input_user3[i];
    En_in3[1] = input_user3[(i+1)];
    SCMA_En (En_in3,CB_3, &CW_U3);
}

for (i=0; i<init_num; i=i+2) {
    En_in4[0] = input_user4[i];
    En_in4[1] = input_user4[(i+1)];
    SCMA_En (En_in4,CB_4, &CW_U4);
}

for (i=0; i<init_num; i=i+2) {
    En_in5[0] = input_user5[i];
    En_in5[1] = input_user5[(i+1)];
    SCMA_En (En_in5,CB_5, &CW_U5);
}

for (i=0; i<init_num; i=i+2) {
    En_in6[0] = input_user6[i];
    En_in6[1] = input_user6[(i+1)];
    SCMA_En (En_in6,CB_6, &CW_U6);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message should have the line number of the error. See it to find where the error came from. By the way, how do you define `CW_U1` - `CW_U6`?

Comment: The assignment for `CB_1` - `CB_6` seems invalid. Assign each elements one by one or use initializer.

Comment: If your own code is difficult for you to understand and debug, you should simplify.

Comment: Odd that you have accidentally written some C code when trying to write C++. You should get a better book.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the initializers correctly.  They need to go with the variable's declarations, and not in an assignment.

You're getting your error because the `CB_1` initializer list starts out with `int`s.  When it reaches the second sub-initializer it is expecting ints, finding _Complex values instead, and generating the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was useful , now I have two more errors!!     "28: error: cannot convert double __complex__ to double __complex__* in assignment"       and      "116: error: cannot convert double __complex__ (*)[4] to double __complex__** for argument 3 to void SCMA_En(char*, double __complex__ (*)[4], double __complex__**)"     , can you suggest me anything?